# I can't run a basic rspec test with haml and rails6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, haml

I started a simple project with rails 6 and haml-rails and rspec and my basic tests are failing on a basic get :home pointing to a simple haml template - I don't really know if it's a haml-rails, haml or rspec problem.

the errors I got

```
# rspec spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb
DEPRECATION WARNING: Single arity template handlers are deprecated.  Template handlers must
now accept two parameters, the view object and the source for the view object.
Change:
  >> Class#call(template)
To:
  >> Class#call(template, source)
 (called from <top (required)> at /home/kuku/Projects/Permission/config/application.rb:22)
DEPRECATION WARNING: action_view.finalize_compiled_template_methods is deprecated and has no effect (called from <top (required)> at /home/kuku/Projects/Permission/config/environment.rb:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: formats is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 6.1 (called from block (3 levels) in <top (required)> at /home/kuku/Projects/Permission/spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:8)
DEPRECATION WARNING: formats is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 6.1 (called from block (3 levels) in <top (required)> at /home/kuku/Projects/Permission/spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:8)
DEPRECATION WARNING: formats is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 6.1 (called from block (3 levels) in <top (required)> at /home/kuku/Projects/Permission/spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:8)
F

Failures:

  1) StaticPagesController GET #home returns http success
     Failure/Error: get :home

     ActionView::Template::Error:
       wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
     # ./spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # ArgumentError:
     #   wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
     #   ./spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.01728 seconds (files took 0.9926 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:7 # StaticPagesController GET #home returns http success
```

my test - `get :home` is line 8

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe StaticPagesController, type: :controller do
  describe 'GET #home' do
    it 'returns http success' do
      get :home
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
end
```

and my controller

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home; end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'static_pages#home'
end
```

I tried to use haml-rails and haml from master branch which seems to have some rails6 fixes but the errors I got are the same errors:

```
gem 'haml', github: 'haml/haml', branch: 'master'
gem 'haml-rails', github: 'indirect/haml-rails', branch: 'master'
```

Any suggestions that I may try or maybe is there any easy way to rollback from rails-haml to erb ?

Comment: You should delete your edit and add it as an answer, that is perfectly fine to do here if you solve your own problem.

Comment: I meant as an answer, not a comment. Maybe you don't have enough reputation points for that, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

I updated rspec and now it passes - it seems that rspec is not ready for rails 6

```
gem 'rspec-rails', github: 'rspec/rspec-rails', branch: '4-0-dev' 
gem 'rspec', github: 'rspec/rspec', branch: 'master' 
gem 'rspec-core', github: 'rspec/rspec-core', branch: 'master' 
gem 'rspec-mocks', github: 'rspec/rspec-mocks', branch: 'master' 
gem 'rspec-expectations', github: 'rspec/rspec-expectations', branch: 'master' 
gem 'rspec-support', github: 'rspec/rspec-support', branch: 'master'
```

Comment: There's a beta version of rspec-rails now that should work with rails 6 if you are interested. Check this RailsConf talk from a few days ago by one of the leads https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPYNMsXju_A

Comment: feb 11 2020, now you must specify branch as: gem 'rspec-rails', github: 'rspec/rspec-rails', branch: '4-0-maintenance'

Comment: Now you can use: gem 'rspec-rails', '4.0.0.beta3'  https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/2177